# Generating arcs with SVG paths

Tags: html, svg

Using the following, I get a perfect semi circle from the specified start and end points;

```
<path 
    d="M100,100 L100,200
        A50,50 0 1, 1 100,100
            " 
    stroke="Black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
```

If the circle was complete, it would have x and y radius 50 (as specified as the first argument of the A part of the path) centred on the arc start point 100,200 and end point 100,100.

If I now update the path to the following;

```
<path 
    d="M100,100 L100,150
        A50,50 0 1, 1 100,100
            " 
    stroke="Black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
```

I see the circle 'spill' out to the left of the line.

Assumption: because the distance between the start and end point of the arc is less than the required 100px (diameter), the centre point of the circle is calculated away from the line drawn between the start and end of the arc, and further is equidistant to these two points. Therefore the specified 50 radius is acting as a minimum radius and will not be 'scaled down' if the distance between the start and end point is less than 2 * radius.

If I now update the path to the following;

```
<path 
    d="M100,100 L100,400
        A50,50 0 1, 1 100,100
            " 
    stroke="Black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
```

If the arc was part of a circle, again (as per the first arc setup) it's centred on the line but this time the x and y radius's have magnified to accommodate the additional distance between the defined start and end points.

Assumption: Whilst the 50px radius acts as a minimum, it does not act as a maximum and in fact will be scaled if the width between the start and end points is > 100 (diameter).

Are any of my assumptions correct or am I off the mark?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcOutOfRangeParameters

Comment: That doesn't explain the instance where the distance between start and end is < than diameter, not that I can see.

Comment: Really? *If rx, ry and φ are such that there is no solution (basically, the ellipse is not big enough to reach from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2)) then the ellipse is scaled up uniformly until there is exactly one solution (until the ellipse is just big enough)*